# OSB 12c REST reference

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, osb

I am trying to consumer a REST service using OSB 12C.
[image]

How can I set the template {projectId} when call this from Route inside pipeline?

I have been trying routing Options, but I can't do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found one way to do this changing the request outbound.

The image below shown what I did:

[image]

- Was necessary insert one user-metadata in request:

  `<tp:user-metadata name='projectId' value='VALUE_GOES_HERE' />`
- Under request location:

  `$outbound/ctx:transport/ctx:request`

Comment: What if i want to send the value dynamically. I have tried static and it is working but this value i need to send dynamically. Can you please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the "transport headers" action for this (not routing options)

Comment: Do you have an example using "transport headers"? 
I have tried for many ways but could not do it!